# How can allocate a,b,c,d to different rows in a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a set of values a,b,c,d I want to create an nx1 vector that allocates the values to different rows based the size of n. If n=9 I want the vector to be [a+b, a, a+c, b, 0, c, b+c, d, c+d] or if n=4 my vector is [a+b, a+c, b+c, c+d]. For row=1 the entry is a+b, for the row sqrt(n) the entry is a+c,the entries in between (i.e., 1 and sqrt(n)) are a. For row=sqrt(n)+ 1 the entry is b, for 2*sqrt(n) entry is c and  the entries in between are a. For row=2*sqrt(n)+1 entry=b+c, for row=n the entry is c+d and the entries in between are d. The different values of n being n=4, 9,25,100,225 and 400. Is there a way of building this vector using a for loop instead of manually creating the nx1 vector and using if statements to allocate the relevant manually created vector?

Answer (score 0):

```
s = {} #set filled with values (a+b,a,a+c...)
n = int(input()) #number of elements you want
l = []
for idx, ele in enumerate(s):
    if idx == n:
        break
    l.append(ele)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've separated n=4 as it is a special case

```
import numpy as np

n = 400
a,b,c,d = 1,2,4,8

result = np.empty((n,1))
sqrtn = n**0.5
if n == 4:
    result[:,0] = [a+b, a+c, b+c, c+d]
else:
    index1 = 0
    index2 = int(sqrtn)-1
    Index3 = int(sqrtn)
    index4 = int(2*sqrtn)-1
    index5 = int(2*sqrtn)
    index6 = int(n)-1
    result[Index3+1:index4] = 0
    result[index1+1:index2] = a
    result[index5+1:index6] = d
    result[index1] = a+b
    result[index2] = a+c
    result[Index3] = b
    result[index4] = c
    result[index5] = b+c
    result[index6] = c+d
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by writing it

```
if n == 9:
    nx1 = [a+b, a, a+c, b, 0, c, b+c, d, c+d]
elif n == 4:
    nx1 = [a+b, a+c, b+c, c+d]
elif ...
```